# Having trouble with a while loop in Swift 5

Tags: swift, while-loop

Essentially, I'm making an app about a virtual dog to help people take care of their dogs. One of the screens gives you fifteen seconds to pet the dog five times. Whenever I try to load the screen, the app freezes. The code is inside of viewDidLoad()

```swift
while timesPetted < 5 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
                timer += 1
                if timer == 15 {
                    self.failureLabel.isHidden = false
                    self.reset.isHidden = false
                    self.timesPetted = 0
                }

            })
        }
```

When I delete the while loop, the screen loads normally and runs perfectly, but (obviously) there isn't a time limit. If I move the while loop out of viewDidLoad(), I get an error saying that Xcode "Expected declaration".

Comment: You have an infinite loop since `timesPetted` is never increased and your whole asyncAfter looks weird with that condition. By pure coincidence I found the [this link](https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md) on loops in another question just earlier.

Comment: This is an infinite loop. And be aware that `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` is called a few 100000 times per second because the while loop is not affected by `asyncAfter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a timer that is set to expire in 15 seconds

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15.0, repeats: false) { timer in
    self.failureLabel.isHidden = false
    self.reset.isHidden = false
    self.timesPetted = 0
 }
```

Or if you want to use DispatchQueue then use it only once

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 15) {
    self.failureLabel.isHidden = false
    self.reset.isHidden = false
    self.timesPetted = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The idea behind the repeating loop was so that every second, the code would check if timesPetted = 5, but I fixed it by using the timer and just putting an if statement before the other three lines of code. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

it appears the while loop is running infinitely due to the value of timesPetted. As the value of timesPetted is not changing at all once it enters the while loop.

To solve your issue you can make changes to your code as below :-

You must be updating your timesPetted value some where in the code.
lets say timesPetted is changed in function called "Petting", so when this function is called have check, which limits the user to pet till 5 times only and another check for 15 seconds. As shown below.

```
   func petting() {
      if reset.isHidden && timesPetted <= 5{ // here the reset.isHidden will become false in DispatchQueue (present in viewDidLoad) once the 15 seconds have been passed.
         timesPetted += 1
      }
   }
```

And also make sure to add this line of code in your viewDidLoad.

```
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 15) {
      self.failureLabel.isHidden = false
      self.reset.isHidden = false
      self.timesPetted = 0
   }
```